# What is wrong with this dependency?

Tags: .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 2 console application, and when I look at the dependencies, under the `SDK` node, there is one dependency, `Microsoft.NETCore.App` that has a little yellow warning symbol on it.

This dependency seems to be an essential part of every .NET Core application, and I have done nothing at all to the project's dependencies myself.

Why is this warning symbol there?

Comment: I'd be interested to know too. Happens to me all the time but doesn't seem to have any impact on compiling or running the application.

Comment: have you tried a clean and restore?

Comment: Isn't there also an accompanying actual warning in the error list? Something about a version mismatch? That's been my experience

Comment: Can you show us what is the warning?

Comment: There is no warning at all.

Comment: @series0ne Yeah, it doesn't appear to have any impact at all. That is part of what makes me curious.

Comment: Please edit the project file and show all the PackageReference for the project.    Also did you by any chance create this project using the Dotnet CLI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually there is a problem with the version of the dependency , the warning is for you to know that the current version of this specific dependency doesn't match other dependencies you have in the project.

Comment: Then Visual Studio is buggy, using the wrong dependency version. It puts that there for all Core projects. I have none of my own dependencies in the project.

Comment: Maybe the problem is that you use  in the same solution 2 projects with Microsoft.NETCore.App  but each project has different version of the dependency, and one project has reference to the other project, and there is the mismatch that accure.